# wait() does not return after child received sigstop

Tags: c, signals, fork, posix, wait

Just as the title says, one process forks waits for its child to receive a SIGSTOP (self sent by the child) but it does not wake up after as if it didn't receive any SIGCHLD (but it actually did, tested with strace).

Anyone any ideas?

```
int main() {
  if (fork()) {
    wait(NULL);
    write(1, "Bye\n", 4);
  } else {
    kill(getpid(), SIGSTOP);
    write(1, "Hello\n", 6);
  }
return 0;
}
```

They both hang, whereas only the child should.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[The specification for `wait`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/wait.html) says that it reports only children that have *exited*, not children that have *stopped*.  You should use

```
waitpid(-1, 0, WUNTRACED);
```

instead.

The flag name `WUNTRACED` is a little cryptic - why isn't it `WSTOPPED`?  This is a point where the standardized `wait*` API brushes up against the not-standardized `ptrace` API.  Compare POSIX's definition of `WUNTRACED`…

> WUNTRACED
>
> The status of any child processes specified by pid that are stopped, and whose status has not yet been reported since they stopped, shall also be reported to the requesting process.

… with its documentation in the [Linux manpage](https://linux.die.net/man/2/waitpid) …

> WUNTRACED
>
> also return if a child has stopped (but not traced via [ptrace](https://linux.die.net/man/2/ptrace)(2)). Status for *traced* children which have stopped is provided even if this option is not specified.

So basically the default behavior of `wait*` has a special case embedded in it for the convenience of people writing debuggers (people writing debuggers will take every convenience they can get) and that special case has been around for so long that it affected the names chosen for `waitpid`'s flags.  (I don't know one way or the other, but I would not be surprised to learn that `ptrace` stops are *older* than job control stops.)

Answer (score 0):

oops, I'll answer myself, I forgot to add WUNTRACED as a wait() option.
The correct function call is waitpid(-1, NULL, WUNTRACED);